# Testing mouse event position with react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, react-testing-library

I want to test an API which uses the mouse position to do some computations. I am using react testing library and mocha.

Something like -

```js
const searchClosestPoint(evt) = {
    const {clientX, clientY} = evt;
    // do some computations
    return result;
}
```

```js
// In my test, assume I have some svg element
const evt = createEvent(someSVGElement, 'mouseoever');
fireEvent(someSVGElement, evt);

expect(searchPoint(evt)).to.equal(expectedResult);
```

However, the clientX and clientY always seems to be 0. Any clue on how this can be done and why it may be happening?

Thanks a lot!